# Java jar crashes when it tries to load a window, no error message

Tags: java, jdk

Whenever I run a Java application that has a user interface, it crashes as soon as the window opens. The window is blank white with no content and shown for about 100 milliseconds. There are no error messages when I run it with `java -jar <myjar>`. The program just appears to simply terminate with no warning or anything. It is a very strange behavior.

I am running Java 1.8 x64 bit. I have tried jarfix but to no avail. This is very frustrating since I have no error messages to share and I can not run anything with a window system.

My JAVA_HOME is not set. The path to the `bin/` file in my JDK is in my path.

I have tried reinstalling Java, using different versions, none have worked so far.

Comment: This issue seems to be swing. When I run a blank program that opens a JFrame, it hangs then exists with `Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)` with no error messages.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 Pro 1903 18362.356

Comment: When I open the JAR on my account that is not linked to a Microsoft account, it works fine. As soon as I switch to my linked account, it stops working. I tried `chmod 777` on my Microsoft account file system via Cygwin which made it open, but the layout is messed up. Strange behavior, may be a permission issue.